# How to pass sequelize through express routes to controller in MVC model in node when using ES6 import/export?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I'm trying to refactor some existing code into an MVC model, and am not sure if I'm messing up the structure, or if I just can't figure out how to pass a variable, but, assuming my structure is good, how do I pass a sequelize instance through an Express route to a controller? Here's my code, hopefully simplified for clarity:

Structure:

```
src/
  db.js
  routes.js
  server.js
  controllers/mycontroller.js
  models/mymodel.js
```

server.js:

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

import { router as routes } from './routes';
import db from './db';

const app = express();

try {
  await db.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}

db.myTable.sync(); // this works fine

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(routes); // this, I think, needs to pass db.myTable

app.listen( 3300, () => {
  console.log('Listening on 3300');
});
```

db.js:

```
'use strict';

import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

import myTableModel from './models/mymodel';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory');
const db = {};

db.authenticate = () => sequelize.authenticate();
db.myTable = myTableModel(sequelize);

export default db;
```

routes.js:

```
import express from 'express';
export const router = express.Router();

import MyController from './controllers/mycontroller';

const myController = new MyController();

... // other routes elided for brevity

router.post('/test', myController.store); // that db.myTable I thought I needed to pass above,
// I think I need to pass again here. Or, alternatively, I could put a constructor into
// MyController and pass it as an arg above when I call 'new MyController', but I still have to
// get it down here into this routes file.
```

mycontroller.js:

```
'use strict';

import MyTableModel from '../models/mymodel'; // This was an experiment I tried, but in retrospect,
// it of course makes no sense. I don't need to import the model, I need to have passed the
// instantiated model down here somehow

export default class MyController {
  store = async (req, res, next) => {
    await MyTable.create({ full: req.body.fullUrl}); // This fails (of course), because
    // MyTable.create doesn't exist here.

    res.redirect('/');
  }
}
```

So, back to the question: assuming this structure looks correct (feel free to comment on that as well), how do I get that `MyTable` sequelize object passed all the way through to the controller, so it can do its thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in calling directly the model ?

```
'use strict';
import { myTable } from '../db';

export default class MyController {
  store = async (req, res, next) => {
    await MyTable.create({ full: req.body.fullUrl}); 

    res.redirect('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. This might be the right answer, and is certainly close, but it presents another issue. If I move the instantiation of the models into db.js and import them directly into the controller, then every time I call a controller I get a new db connection. This might well work in production (though it's certainly extra overhead), but definitely doesn't work with the sqlite::memory that I'm using in the dev environment, because every reload connects to a new, empty database. Thoughts?

Comment: The model definition is already in the db.js file : `db.myTable = myTableModel(sequelize);`